# How to sync cryptogen tool generated keys with fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I using the fabric in my project,

```
1.I have generated the keypairs using the cryptogen tool.
2.I have initiated the fabric ca server using CA key, which is generated using above cryptogen tool.
3.I enroll the admin to the fabric CA its generate the wallet with private key and public key and certificate.
4.Then i register the user to that fabric ca server i get the user certificate, private key.
5. Then i create the channel and install the chain code and initiate it.
```

When i query chain code from node js with the user register above, its throw the error

> MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Do i need to provide any details related to fabric ca while generating the cryptogen tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fama,

```
MSP error: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Probably, you have used certificates for the network issued by one CA

Later you created admin certs with another CA

That's why it is complaining

Delete all containers, clear everything and start again make sure you don't generate certs from cryptogen twice

Comment: Thanks for response,I sloved it, the fabric ca and cryptogen  tool generated x509 certificate was mismatching.